# How to set text to view from drawer header layout in navigation drawer without inflating view

Tags: android, material-design

I want to set text to the navigation drawers headers text, I searched a lot but everyone does it by inflating a layout but for me it creates 2 headers so is there any way to set it without inflating the layout?

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

View header=navigationView. findViewById(R.id.header);
/*View        view=navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);*/
name = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.username);
email = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.email);
name.setText(personName);
email.setText(personEmail);`
```

Answer (score 174, accepted):

You get navigation header view by navigationView.getHeaderView(0) , try code below

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
/*View view=navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_main);*/
name = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.username);
email = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.email);
name.setText(personName);
email.setText(personEmail);
```

Comment: @david glorioso 1 year??

Comment: @Manish Yadav if u want to set text from fragment then u can simply access activity component  by using getActivity()

Comment: I am not able to access this from fragment .....**navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);**

Comment: @Manish Yadav just pass your activity context or use getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);