# I am unable to use Textview from different xml file

Tags: android

I have a navigation header I want the name of the user to be displayed on the navigation bar

This is where I added the text view in navigation_header.xml
[image]
I want to use it while loading the user information right here:
Kindly help
[image]

Comment: Check `user.getDisplayName` is not null

Comment: It's not null I already checked that. I just want to use the textview defined in navigation_header.xml and make it equal to user.getDisplayName

Comment: check the image files i provided

Comment: please post your xml and java code here. Without it we can't help you

Comment: Might be this is your sollution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33999635/4491576

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya I'm testing that solution :)

Comment: @Shruti it makes the application to crash as we

Comment: @Kabir share that crash here!

Comment: @AmrishKakadiya It's fixed by your solution Thanks Alot

Comment: In the future, please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: @Shruti Thanks for helping :) Here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33999407/how-to-set-text-to-view-from-drawer-header-layout-in-navigation-drawer-without-i/33999635#33999635

Comment: Okay Mike I'll be careful next time

Answer (score 0):

To access views inside Navigation Header,you have to get HeaderView first.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navViewID);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View header=navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
userName = (TextView)header.findViewById(R.id.userTextViewID);

userName.setText("Your user Name from Firebase");
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, Really Appreciate it...

Comment: if it worked for you. then don't forget to accept it as Answer